# Realloc dynamic array inside of structure

Tags: c, struct, realloc, flexible-array-member

I have a structure :

```
  struct Node{      

        struct Node* pointer[0];  
        int num; 
    } *current=NULL;
```

and then in function I trying to create children to node

```
void AddChild(struct Node *node) {
    uint8_t n=2; // number of add children
    for(uint8_t i=n; i-->0;){
        struct Node* leaf=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //allocate memory to child
        struct Node* tmp=(struct Node*)realloc(node->pointer,(++node->num)*sizeof(struct Node*)); //reallocate memory for dynamic array mistake
        if (!tmp)
            printf("Error in memory alocation\n");
        node->pointer[node->num]=leaf;  
    }
}
```

The problem is that realloc give me error.

> realloc(): invalid pointer:

So if it was c++ I can make a vector and just push back the element, but with c I need to reallocate the array of pointers. How can I  reallocate the memory?

Comment: `struct Node* pointer[0];`--> `struct Node **pointer;` and Rewrite according to this change.

Comment: `node->pointer` is not a pointer; furthermore, the pointer you pass to `realloc` must be a pointer that was allocated with `malloc`/`realloc`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this looks like a problem of `realloc` but your problem is using an array of size zero in the middle of a `struct`.  See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) for an explanation of zero length arrays in `gcc`, also called *flexible array members* in C99, and specifically:

> Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty.